# transfered img to canvas (with a jquery plugin), how to continue working with the canvas?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i wrote a nice plugin which transforms IMG to canvas

```
jQuery.fn.img2canvas = function() { 

      return this.each(function(){

        if($(this).get(0).tagName=='IMG'&&$(this).parent().get(0).tagName!='CANVAS')
        {
            //alert($(this).get(0).tagName);
            $(this).load(function()
            {
                var c = $("<canvas class=' img2canvas'>"+$(this).outerHTML()+"</canvas>");
                //var c = $("<canvas></canvas>");
                $(c).attr('width', this.width);
                $(c).attr('height', this.height);
                var ctx = $(c)[0].getContext( "2d" );
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = $(this).attr('src');
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                $(c).data('imgsrc', this.src);
                $(c).attr('id', $(this).attr('id')+'_canvas');
                $(this).replaceWith($(c));
            });
        }
     });


    };
```

so far so good. but there is no way i can continue working with these canvas.

```
$('img').img2canvas(); //creating the canvas
$('.img2canvas').css('border', '6px solid red'); //but there is no canvas yet
$('canvas').each(function(){alert($(this).data('imgsrc'));}); // still no canvas
$('.img2canvas').each(function(){alert($(this).data('imgsrc'));}); //still no canvas
```

does not help.

what do i need to do to keep the plugin architecture and being able to continue working on the canvas elements? you can see a live demo here http://www.andcontext.com/inimad/sto_demo.php

thx for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assign a callback feature to run when the Image has loaded

```
jQuery.fn.img2canvas = function(callback)
{

      return this.each(function(){

        if($(this).get(0).tagName=='IMG'&&$(this).parent().get(0).tagName!='CANVAS')
        {
            //alert($(this).get(0).tagName);
            $(this).load(function()
            {
                var c = $("<canvas class=' img2canvas'>"+$(this).outerHTML()+"</canvas>");
                //var c = $("<canvas></canvas>");
                $(c).attr('width', this.width);
                $(c).attr('height', this.height);
                var ctx = $(c)[0].getContext( "2d" );
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = $(this).attr('src');
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                $(c).data('imgsrc', this.src);
                $(c).attr('id', $(this).attr('id')+'_canvas');
                $(this).replaceWith($(c));
                callback(this);
            });
        }
     });
};

$('img').img2canvas(function(canvas){
    //...
});
```

This is so basically the anonymous function passed in will be called each time the image has loaded and the canvas has been created

Comment: hi, as basically "this" in the plugin still holds the IMG, "callback(this)" works on the image. "callback($(c))" works fine. thx. it's a way to do it. is it the right way to do it?

Comment: yes, anonymous callbacks are the normal way to issue callbacks during an event trigger process.

Comment: hi, i published a cleaned up code of the img2canvas function here http://www.andcontext.com/comics/image-2-canvas-jquery-plugin - i changed it in a way that it returns a jQuery collection of the newly created canvas elements, and the canvas elements trigger an load event after they were successfully inserted into the DOM. this is necessary to enable easy working with more than one created canvas element.

Comment: Congratulation, also there's a few spelling mistakes in your page :)